# SimpleDateFormat giving a wrong formatted output

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have one function which takes input a string value like *3-2020*. I want to parse this string as a date and change its format to something like *March-2020* using `SimpleDateFormat` class. Here is the code I am using for this task:

```java
public String getCurrentMonth(String day) throws ParseException {
    Date today = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-YYYY").parse(day);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-YYYY").format(today);
}
```

but it is giving a very different output string. When the input provided as *4-2020*, it returns value as *December-2020*. The `today` variable has a value *Sun Dec 29 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2019*. There is a huge difference in the dates. Why is it happening? and how to solve this?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `YearMonth` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Y` is the format for the week year. It looks like you intended to use `y`, which is the format for the year:

```java
public String getCurrentMonth(String day) throws ParseException {
    Date today = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy").parse(day);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy").format(today);
}
```

Comment: exactly, it solved and cleared the meaning of notation with difference of `Y` and `y`

Answer (score 1):

Please use this small y instead of Y

```
Date today = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy").parse("04-2020");
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy").format(today));
```